# Local variable scope

Tags: c#

I would like to have some geek advice here since I can’t brainstorm more.

```
class sampleType
    {
        public void M1(bool someValue)
        {
            if (someValue)
            {
                int a = 1;
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                goto comehere;
            }
            else
            {
                int a = 2;
                Console.WriteLine(a);
                goto comehere;
            }

        comehere:
            {
                int a = 3;
                Console.WriteLine(a);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Assumption:** M1 is jitted and ready to execute. M1 is the last item in the thread stack (last register).

**Question:** How current stack register denote local variables of M1? Especially scope of ‘a’ at if/else/goto block.

Comment: http://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: Start by reading MSIL in Debug configuration. In Release configuration, I beleive, M1 is replaced by constant.

Comment: You niether need to know nor care unless you are working on a compiler for IL

Comment: @Jodrell: Well, there's nothing wrong with curiosity and wondering how things work under the hood -- as long as you keep in mind that you must not base the correctness of your software on undocumented behavior.

Comment: @Heinzi, you are ofc right. Whilst I think it is unlikely to apply here, one should be mindful of the Law of Leaky Abstractions http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html

Comment: @Heinzi -> Thank you for reading me.
@Jodrell-> It’s my curiosity.

Comment: @Jodrell: Thanks for the link, that was an interesting article.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the IL level, either:

1) The three non-overlapping local variables "a" will be generated as a single temporary storage slot and re-used; we know this is safe because they do not overlap, they are all the same type, and they have the same name, so there is no chance the debugger will get confused about them.  or:

2) The three local variables "a" will be generated as three different temporary storage slots, or

3) The three local variables "a" will be determined to be single-assignment and side-effect-free constants, and logically turned into constants, not variables. I do not believe we perform this optimization at this time but we reserve the right to in the future.

At the jitter level, the jitter is free to do whatever it pleases. It can generate a single stack slot. It can assign a single register. It can generate multiple stack slots, it can assign multiple registers. It can treat them as constants. What the jitter can do is limited only by the cleverness of the jitter team. There is no requirement whatsoever that this uses any stack at all.

Comment: Why is there a concept of local variables at the IL at all? Wouldn't the stack(talking about the theoretical stack the CIL instructions work on, not memory x86 uses to store some of the local variables) be enough?

Comment: @CodeInChaos: How do you propose that said stack be used to store local variables? You only get to access the *top* of that stack. You need some way to talk about "this value over there that I pushed onto the stack a while back", and you might as well call out that that is a local variable.

Comment: I thought that there was a `dup<index>` instruction like there is in lua. But looking over the instruction list it doesn't seem to exist. But you're right, it's not much different from calling it a local variable. And calling it a local variable has a few advantages, for example makes interaction with a debugger a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear to me what you're trying to determine - what the C# language guarantees in terms of behaviour, what the compiled IL will look like, or what the JIT-compiled native code will look like.

In terms of IL, I'd *expect* these to end up as separate local variables in the method metadata. It's *possible* that the JIT will notice that it can manage with a single stack allocation and reuse it for all three variables. However, you should neither know nor care whether that happens. The three `a` variables are logically distinct and *will not* interfere with each other.

(If that doesn't answer your question, please clarify *exactly* what you're trying to determine...)

Answer (score 2):

As Eric Lippert writes: [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx). How local variables are mapped to the stack depends on the jitter implementation. It's not specified by the language.